# How to send push notification via pushwoosh for web(Chrome, Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pushwoosh

I have successfully integrate pushwoosh for Chrome, Firefox and successfully Subscribed for Chrome, Firefox.

I have followed following link for it:
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/web-sdk-20

I have taken the following steps:

- Removed any references to the old service-worker.js from my site.
- Included the manifest link in my header (before any other manifest links).
- Removed my site in firefox notification settings so I will be prompted to allow notifications again.
- Uploaded pushwoosh-service-worker-light.js and pushwoosh-service-worker-dark.js to my site root.
- Included the code in my site header as per the sdk 2.0 documentation(adjusting applocationCode variable etc as necessary)
- Clear the cache in firefox browser and cloudflare, verified new code is in place via "view source".
- Visit my site on firefox, get prompted to allow notifications and select "always allow notifications".
- Log into pushwoosh control panel, I show as a new subscriber okay.
- Send pushwoosh to firefox only to test but the new firefox subscriber gets removed and the notification never delivers.

But when I have tried to sent push notification from pushwoosh (https://go.pushwoosh.com/applications/xxxxx-xxxxx)

then I have got following error in Push History
(https://go.pushwoosh.com/notifications?field=application&value=xxxxx-xxxxx) for Chrome and Firefox.

Error for chrome:

> "The device token has expired, or the application was unregistered
>   from notifications"

Error for Firefox:

> "The pushtoken is not recognized by Mozilla"

and auto unsubscribed form chrome and firefox.

I think I am missing something for integration.
How to send push notification via pushwoosh for web(Chrome, Firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Pushwoosh support (https://www.pushwoosh.com/contact-us/) and describe your issue. Add the link to your site and your Pushwoosh login/username.